# Several table formatting issues with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am almost finished with the first outline of my comparison table that I'm trying to create. I have encountered some issues though that I cannot solve. And I've tried different classes, id's and properties, but it either end up doing nothing or changing something that was not intended. Some issues I solved on my own though.

Instead of posting several questions one by one, spamming SO. I put a hold on myself and grouped my questions together. So here it goes:

**My Goal:**

To the far left, I want to create a column that first is blank and then holds all the titles of each row.
Then I want each row that will contain a product to follow a falling sequence of:
 1. Product image
2. company name
3. product name
4. price
5. button
6. HERE IS A WHITE BLANK ROW: With a category title (e.g.Functions or Compability).
7. First title in left td (e.g. audio, video). Then continuing the falling sequence with a check or x-mark in each cell, depending on that product includes named specification (audio..video.. etc)

**My problem are these:**

How do I get everything centred above each other? Except Left column titles which are supposed to be left-aligned.
How do I make all rows above the Category title-row, without the hover effect?
How to make the "Category Title" to rest on the 2px solid gray border?
How to make all rows above Category Title to become white?
Is there a better way to make this border in a more efficient way?

```
/* thick border for the top row */
#borderbottom{
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
```

I figure that i should probably make two separate tables CSS for each table, but when I tried, the two tables did not align with each other.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Compare Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
  <br/>

<table class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td>IMAGE</td>
    <td>IMAGE</td>
    <td>IMAGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td>Company Name<br/>Product Name</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr> 
</table> 


<table class="hoverTable">
  <tr id="notop">
  <td class="blankcell" id="borderbottom"><h3>Category Title</h3></td>
    <td id="borderbottom"></td>
    <td id="borderbottom"></td> 
    <td id="borderbottom"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="rowTitle" colspan="4">TITLE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="check">&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="x01">&#x2716</td>
    <td>&#x2716</td> 
    <td>&#x2716</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="nolast">
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
th,td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Row coloring */
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
/* Upper left cell*/
.blankcell {
    background: none!important; 
    text-align: left;
}
/*top and bottom border*/
#notop{
    border:0px;
}
#nolast{
    border-bottom:0px;
}

/* HOVER FUNCTION */
.hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .hoverTable td{ 
        padding:4px; 
        border: #000000 0px solid;
    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    .hoverTable tr{
        background: #ffffff;
        border-bottom:1px solid #B5B3B3;
        border-top:1px solid #B5B3B3;
    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover {
        background-color: #FFF0E6;
        border-left:5px solid #ff6600;
    }
/* Check and X-Mark Coloring*/
#check {
    color: #1CF200;
}
#x01 {
    color: #ff6969;
}
/* Left-hand title */
.rowTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
/* thick border for the top row */
#borderbottom{
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v76ms7mz/)

Thank you for any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How do I get everything centred above each other? Except Left column titles which are supposed to be left-aligned.**

All of the content is already being center. You already have code to left align text. It's being used on the bottom table for the first column.

```
.rowTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

**How to make the "Category Title" to rest on the 2px solid gray border?** Add the class category in the h3 tag

```
h3.category {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}
```

**How do I make all rows above the Category title-row, without the hover effect?**

You can use separate code that just doesn't use the hover code. Basically copy the hovertable with ".hoverTable tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover" and call the new class something like toptable. (There might be a more efficient way.

**How to make all rows above Category Title to become white?**

If you use seperate code with basically the same values just don't copy over

```
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

**Is there a better way to make this border in a more efficient way?** I would use a  tag for Category. The colspan will span the 4 columns below it.

CSS

```
th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}
```

HTML

```
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th colspan="4">Category Title</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

See some of these applied to this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x6co362t/

Yes you should make 2 different set of codes as this will solve most of your problems. How do they not align up? Can you should what is supposed to be aligned up?

Comment: You really went above and beyond for the OP...+1 bro...i wish everyone +1'd the people that deserve it...